# how to have jquery change function on a select dropdown to work when page is loaded?

Tags: jquery

I am going nuts with this.
I have dropdown filters in our website. This is the html code of the dropwdown in question:

```
echo "<div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4'><label for='league'>Privacidad:</label>`";`
echo "<select id='page_private_id' class='page_filter'>";
echo "<option value=-1>Todas</option>";
echo "<option value=0 selected>Públicas</option>";
echo "<option value=1>Privadas</option>";
echo "</select></div>";
```

we have the following jquery function that executes on selection:

```
jQuery('select.page_filter').change(function(){
    var privacy = jQuery('#page_private_id').val();
if(privacy != -1)
        {
            criteria["made_by"] = privacy;
        }
```

Once the page is loaded dropdown menu selects the option we want as default but it does not execute the change in jquery until you select another option and then come back to this one. the jquery code works well. But, how can I accomplish this default execution?

UPDATE:
I tried adding `:selected` after `#page_private_id`, it did not solve it.

Comment: 1) Your first `echo` doesn't appear to end correctly. 2) Why are you using `echo` to dump a big chunk of static HTML?

Comment: What have you tried? It should be as simple as `jQuery($ => { $('select.page_filter').change() })`

Comment: The `.change()` function only runs automatically when the user changes the selection in the menu.

Comment: @Phil Lots of PHP programmers use `echo` to output HTML. It's just personal style.

Comment: @Barmar I see, so how can it run when page loads and know about the current selection? Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar I know but in my experience it just leads to string quoting confusion. Even `HEREDOC` format is better though I really just recommend jumping out of the PHP context

Comment: @Phil Its a chunk of a php file rendering the html page.

Comment: @Joekom yes, I know exactly what it is

Comment: @Phil There are far better windmills to tilt at, IMHO. :)

Comment: @Barmar nice, I'll have to remember that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `.change()` method explicitly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var criteria = {};
  $("select.page_filter").change(function() {
    var privacy = jQuery('#page_private_id').val();
    if (privacy != "-1") {
      criteria["made_by"] = privacy;
    }
    console.log(criteria);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4'><label for='league'>Privacidad:</label>
  <select id='page_private_id' class='page_filter'>
<option value=-1>Todas</option>
<option value=0 selected>Públicas</option>
<option value=1>Privadas</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: you seem to be an expert but is the syntax correct? I added the change method as explained and made a mess in the website.

Comment: Pretty sure, this will work. Late by 18 seconds @Barmar ;)

Comment: I might be adding it in the wrong place. its a very long document. Thank you guys very much.